# Saving rows and columns in database

Tags: c#, foreach

I am trying to save a large cvs file into the database. The file i am using is about 7000 rows and each row contains 14 columns. I have to generate and tag each column of every row with a topic id i pass in my api. After saving each item i then loop through the actual data and i use the generated id to save each data in another table. My problem is i have nested foreach loops and in the first loop i call db.saveChanges() after taking each column in every row so i can reference the generated id. but that is A LOT of saveChanges() calls that are made before processing the data.

For an example:

```
public static void Save(TopicRequest req){
   using(var db = new DbContext()){
      foreach(var row in req.items){
        var obj = new Entity{
             topicId = req.topicId,
             year = req.year
        };
        db.Add(obj);
        db.saveChanges();
      
        foreach(var col in row){
          var newData = new Entity{
             TopicObjId = obj.id,
             Value = col 
          }
        db.TopicData.Add(newData);
        }
        db.saveChanges();
    }
  }
}
```

so for a 7000 row file with 14 columns that means that my first loop will make a call to save into the db 98,000 times. This is causing a timeout and the file saved. How can i probably handle such large amounts of data in this way.

Comment: You probably don't have to "save every time so you can reference the generated id" but you haven't really posted enough code to be able to advise on how to alter the process. Post the full code, including the code for whatever class `db` is

Comment: @CaiusJard so my problem is my first foreach loop. How can go about not calling save each time since the id is created after saving into the db and that id is what i use in my inner loop.

Comment: Post the code requested in the first comment so we can have a look at the process end to end.

Comment: EF will automatically create and update the `id` when you save outside of the loop. I ran into a similar question when i tried to do the same thing years ago, but EF handles it in the background. Scaffold a temporary database with the same schema and run your CSV import against it.

Comment: It is a web based application? Do you have also a client side scripting?

Comment: To me the code looks like you call SaveChanges twice for each row, not for each element.

Comment: @JayGould wow, didn't realize that. I just tried keeping the db.saveChanges outside the loops and all the data saved but the topicObjId for all the columns is 0.

Comment: @JayGould do you guarantee EF is in use? It doesn't have a camelcase `saveChanges` method and Add is called on a set, not a context..

Comment: @bluePearl post the code of the class that `db` is an instance of, or if this is EF(Core) and it's a context, please make absolutely sure the code here is the actual code being run (`db.Add(obj);` looks weird, as does `saveChanges` with a lowercase s), and post the definitions of the entities involved)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use AddRange to improve the performance.

[Add vs AddRange](https://entityframework.net/improve-ef-add-performance)

Here's an example:

```
public async Task Save(TopicRequest req)
{
  using(var db = new DbContext())
  {
    var list1 = new List<Entity1>();
    var list2 = new List<Entity2>();

    foreach(var row in req.items)
    {
      var obj = new Entity1 
      {
        topicId = req.topicId,
        year = req.year
      };
      list1.Add(obj);
    }

    db.Topic.AddRange(list1);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    // this may not be necessary
    await db.Entry(list1).ReloadAsync():
    
    foreach(var obj in list1)
    {    
      var newData = new Entity2 
      {
        TopicObjId = obj.topicId,
        Value = obj.value
      };
      list2.Add(newData);
    }

    db.TopicData.AddRange(list2);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
  }
}
```